# Program starting at integer value 97?

Tags: c++

following Stroustrup's Principles book to learn some C++ during my winter break. I am struggling to understand why the following example (taken off of another stackoverflow thread) outputs an integer value of 97.

The original challenge goes something like this: use a loop to write out a table of characters with their corresponding integer values.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
    cout << "letter " << c << " has value " << int(c) << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

To me, (novice) I read it as the following: char c = 'a'. If 'a' is less than or equal to 'z', increment the letter by 1. Where are the integer values coming from? And why are they starting at 97?

Comment: "Why is this C++ program" - and why did you add a tag for an unrelated language?

Comment: Because, `97` is decimal representation of character `a` in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif).

Comment: Letters are encoded as numbers and stored in `char` bytes. It's a convention.

Comment: Your answer is in this table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Apparently on your system the character `'a'` is represented by the numeric value 97.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: 10 year ago such question couldn't even be close to possible or was  supposing direct way out of door of computer science dep. Do they really teach anything now to students? `char' is C++ byte, as long as you stay with ASCII code table, each letter represented with single byte. Casting char to int doesn't change the value, empty digits will be filled by 0.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for that.

Comment: Appreciate the pointers on ASCII. Makes so much more sense.

Comment: @Swift, easy. I'll take this as a learning experience. I am actually readying myself for my first programming class so I'm glad I asked now and was able to figure it out with the help of some seasoned professionals.

Comment: Don't believe too much in ASCII. It's probably not the character set and encoding you are using. Go `locale` or `chcp` to find out which your terminal/console is using. For files, you just have to know which the writer used, and when writing, use the one that your readers will know that you are using. One very important reader to you, as the writer of source code text files, is your compiler. It probably has a default encoding and a switch to override it.

Comment: @TomBlodget https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ 

After reading your post, I read the article above, and I'm glad I KIND OF have a better sense of encoding/character sets now. THANK YOU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the ASCII value of `'a'` to see them all check out http://www.asciitable.com/. The computer internally stores the number 97 when it wants to store that character.

Note that ASCII is only 7 bits so handles values 0-127, everything higher than that requires either extended ASCII or some form of Unicode which all gets complex.

Answer (score 2):

The integer values in question are the ASCII, and ISO-8859-*, and Unicode, and various other, codes for the letters in question.  In particular, 97 (decimal) is the code for lowercase Latin 'a' in all of those encodings.

Note, however, that although these particular codes for are quite common, they are not *universal*, and C++ does not require use of any of them.  For example, EBCDIC uses different codes, and it is possible to construct a conforming C++ implementation that uses EBCDIC.  On such an implementation, your program would produce different output.

Answer (score 1):

> Where are the integer values coming from? And why are they starting at 97?

It comes from ASCII 7-bit encoding. Refer to character `a` in [the ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).